# Android sending image over socket fails: "client.getOutputStream()" does not work

Tags: android, sockets

I can't get this code to work, in particular, the instruction "outputStream = client.getOutputStream();" does not seem to work and I can't figure out why. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance guys

```
public class FileActivity extends Activity {

private FileInputStream fileInputStream;
 private BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
 private OutputStream outputStream;

private byte [] mybytearray;

private String tmp = null;

private TextView tv;

private File myFile;

private int l;

private String path;

private EditText editText;

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

private Socket client;

public static String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";

private final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private byte [] imgbyte;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

    Thread sThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    sThread.start();
}

public void sendListener(View v) {

    tmp = editText.getText().toString();

    path = "/sdcard/" + tmp;

    myFile = new File(path);Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");           

    l = (int) myFile.length();Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");

    tv.setText(path + "  " + Integer.toString(l));  

    tmp = Integer.toString(l);  Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");

    String test = tmp;



    //out.println(tmp);
    Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
    try {

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())), true);
        out.println(test);
        out.close();
        Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[l]; //create a byte array to file
        Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
         bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);  
         Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");

         bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); //read the file
         Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
         try{
             outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
         } catch(Exception e)
         {
             Log.d("OUTPUT", "UFFFF");
         }
         Log.d("SERVER", "ALMOST");
         outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); Log.d("SERVER", "DONE");//write file to the output stream byte by byte
        /* outputStream.flush();
         try{
             outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
         } catch(Exception e)
         {
             Log.d("OUTPUT", "UFFFF");
         }*/

       /*  
         Log.d("SERVER", "FUUUNZIONAAAA");
         int count = 0;

         while((count = bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0 , mybytearray.length)) != -1)
         {
             Log.d("SERVER", "FINEEEE");
             outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
             Log.d("TEST", Integer.toString(count));
         }
         Log.d("SERVER", "FINEEEE");
         bufferedInputStream.close();
         outputStream.close();
               client.close();*/
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

        /*
    }

    Log.d("SERVER", "FUUUNZIONAAAA");
    tv.setText(path + "  " + Integer.toString(l));      

    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())), true);
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        os = client.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {   
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte[l]; 
        Log.d("SERVER", "FUUUNZIONAAAA");

        Log.d("SERVER", "FUUUNZIONAAAA");
        out.println(Integer.toString(l));
        Log.d("SERVER", "INVIATO0");

        int read_count = 0;
        while ((read_count = bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length)) != -1) {
            os.write(mybytearray, 0, read_count); // Now writes the correct amount of bytes
        }

        Log.d("SERVER", "INVIATO1");

        out.close();
        fis.close();
        bis.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } */


}


public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            client = serverSocket.accept();
            //outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

            Log.d("SERVER", "Connesso");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TEST", "UFFFAAA");
        }           
    }

}

private String getLocalIpAddress() {

    String tmp = "";

    int i = 0;

    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) 
                { 

                    tmp += "IP: " + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n"; 

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
    }
    return tmp;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
         serverSocket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

}

This is the error I'm getting

```
06-25 01:01:41.504: W/System.err(22561): java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.checkNotClosed(PlainSocketImpl.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.getOutputStream(PlainSocketImpl.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at com.illiano.esameserver.FileActivity.sendListener(FileActivity.java:120) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 06-25 01:01:41.504:
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: When I see a question saying "it doesn't work" without explaining *in which way* it doesn't work, I'll vote to close as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" or "unclear what you're asking" 9 times out of 9. "It doesn't work" doesn't give anyone a starting point for examining the problem. Explain what results you're getting and how they differ from the intended results, and include any error messages you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
```

means that *you* closed the socket and then continued to use it.

Possibly you are unaware that closing the input stream or output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I really don't see how the socket can be closed. I close the socket only once and that is in the OnStop function.. could you please show me where in the code the mistake is? Thanks in advance